# XMLHttpRequest issue when using D3 library

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently trying to run a simple library called [metricsgraphics.js](http://metricsgraphicsjs.org/). It's d3 library that I was super excited about using but I am having some issues getting it to run. It looks like a pretty simple library to use, but I keeping getting errors. I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <link href="lib/metricsgraphics.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/metricsgraphics.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      d3.json('data/ufo-sightings', function(data) {
      })

      d3.json('data/ufo-sightings', function(data) {
        data = MG.convert.date(data, 'year');

      })

      d3.json('data/ufo-sightings', function(data) {
            MG.data_graphic({
                title: "UFO Sightings",
                description: "Yearly UFO sightings from the year 1945 to 2010.",
                data: data,
                width: 650,
                height: 150,
                target: '#ufo-sightings',
                x_accessor: 'year',
                y_accessor: 'sightings',
                markers: [{'year': 1964, 'label': '"The Creeping Terror" released'}]
            })
        })
    </script>
  </body>
```

I am following their directions on their website. I getting following two error messages

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///directory/where/my/data/is. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load file:///directory/where/my/data/is.
```

Can anyone help me interpret and offer a possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running your source directly in the browser which ends up making a JSON request to a file url, not allowed under the security constraints of the browser, as the error tells you. While you can browbeat different browsers to allow this, a much safer and simpler solution is to set up your development environment so you serve this over http.